# Does Nei's Standard Genetic "Distance" obey identity of indiscernibles?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, symmetric-functions, triangle-inequality

In [Nei 1972](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/282771) he describes what is now called [Nei's standard genetic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_distance#Nei%27s_standard_genetic_distance). He defines at as follows:

> Consider two randomly mating diploid populations, $X$ and $Y$, in which multiple alleles aggregrate at a locus. Let $x_i$ and $y_i$ be the frequencies of the $i$th alleles in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. The probability of identity of two randomly chosen genes is $j_X = \sum x_i^2$ in population $X$, while it is $j_Y = \sum y_i^2$ in population $Y$. The probability of identity of a gene from $X$ and a gene from $Y$ is $j_{XY} = \sum x_iy_i$. [...] The normalized identity of genes between $X$ and $Y$ with respect to this locus is defined as $$I_j = \frac{j_{XY}}{\sqrt{j_Xj_Y}}.$$[...] The normalized identity of genes between $X$ and $Y$ with respect to all loci is defined as $$I = \frac{J_{XY}}{\sqrt{J_XJ_Y}},$$ where $J_X$, $J_Y$ and $J_{XY}$ are the arithmetic means of $j_X$, $j_Y$, and $j_{XY}$, respectively, over all loci, including monomorphic loci. [...] The genetic distance between $X$ and $Y$ is then defined as $$D = - \log_e I.$$

He states in this work that his function does not have the triangle inequality.

> In the present measure of genetic distance, the triangle inequality, which is often assumed in numerical taxonomy (see, e.g., Levandowsky and Winter 1971), does not hold.

Nei also said, ["*Evolution does not occur so as to assure this property at least at the nucleotide level.*"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/107253/what-did-masatoshi-nei-1972-mean-by-however-evolution-does-not-occur-so-as-to) in reference to the triangle inequality.

Not having the triangle inequality disqualifies Nei's score from being a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). I am curious if any of the other properties of a metric fail to hold.

- Due to the product of probabilities and norms always being non-negative, and the negative log of a number on $[0,1]$, it seems clear that it has the non-negativity property.
- The symmetry property also holds because of the commutativity of scalar multiplication.
- It is clear that $D[X,X] = 0$, but does the stronger identity of indiscernibles hold? While [identity of indiscernibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles) has a broader meaning, in this context of a metric I more narrowly mean $D[X,Y] = 0 \iff X = Y$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the definition of the function you are talking about in the question. Likewise what is the "identity of indiscernibles"? That may not be "non-standard terminology", but because it is the crux of your question, it would be helpful to make sure it is defined clearly.

Comment: @Chill2Macht I agree. I have added an excerpt of Nei 1972 where he defines the function. I have also stated what I mean by "identity of indiscernibles". Let me know if these are satisfactory changes.

Comment: OK, so we're not considering linkage between loci, right? So the loci can be treated as independent random variables/distributions? At least, if I'm reading/understanding the definition correctly, since you're just taking the arithmetic mean over loci, there isn't really any way for "non-linear" phenomena like that to "creep in" when going from $j_X$/$j_Y$/$j_{XY}$ to $J_X$/$J_Y$/$J_{XY}$, right? If so I would focus first on the single-locus case. In particular, can you prove/disprove any relationship between whether id. of ind. holds for the single-locus case vs. whether it holds generally?

Comment: Sorry, so isn't $I_j$ (the definition for a single-locus) just the "uncentered empirical correlation" of the two frequency vectors $(x_1, \dots, x_i, \dots)$ and $(y_1, \dots, y_i, \dots)$? And do we say that populations $X$ and $Y$ are equal, $X=Y$, if and only if all of their frequency vectors for all of their loci are equal? Is that correct? So the first question would be, for simple organisms with a single locus, if $X=Y$ if and only if that "uncentered empirical correlation$ equals $1$, correct? almost certainly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Answer (score 2):

(a) when the number of loci is exactly $1$, then yes, the identity definitely holds
(b) when the number of loci is greater than $1$, then I doubt it, but I don't have a proof/specific counterexample

(a) In this case $X = (x_1, \dots, x_i, \dots, x_I)$ and $Y= (y_1, \dots, y_i, \dots, y_I)$ where $I$ is the number of alleles for the single locus. Both of these are probability/frequency vectors, so non-negative entries summing to 1.

Then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that the dot product $\sum_{i=1}^I x_i y_i$ equals the product of the norms $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1^I} x_i^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1^I} y_i^2}$, i.e. their ratio equals 1, i.e. the negative logarithm of their ratio (Nei distance) equals $0$, **if and only if** the two vectors are collinear (scalar multiples of each other).

However, two non-negative vectors whose entries are both constrained to the same value can be scalar multiples of each other if and only if they are equal.

(b) Let $L$ equal the number of loci, and for each $\ell = 1, \dots, L$, let $I_{\ell}$ denote the number of alleles for the $\ell$'th locus. Then
$$X = ( (x^{(1)}_1, \dots, x^{(1)}_{i_1}, \dots, x^{(1)}_{I_1}), \dots,(x^{(\ell)}_1, \dots, x^{(\ell)}_{i_\ell}, \dots, x^{(\ell)}_{I_\ell}) , \dots, (x^{(L)}_1, \dots, x^{(L)}_{i_L}, \dots, x^{(L)}_{I_L}))   $$
$$Y = ( (y^{(1)}_1, \dots, y^{(1)}_{i_1}, \dots, y^{(1)}_{I_1}), \dots,(y^{(\ell)}_1, \dots, y^{(\ell)}_{i_\ell}, \dots, y^{(\ell)}_{I_\ell}) , \dots, (y^{(L)}_1, \dots, y^{(L)}_{i_L}, \dots, y^{(L)}_{I_L}))  \,, $$
where each vector in the vector of vectors is a probability vector.

So the identity of indiscernibles should probably fail for more general reasons here. I think it should not be too hard to find a counterexample that bites you because of (i) symmetry on a per-locus basis, (ii) that the definitions of the $J_X$, $J_Y$, $J_{XY}$ are arithmetic means over the loci (and thus symmetric over the loci).

As an example of this, let $L=2$, with $I_1 = I_2 = 2$. So
$$X = ((x_1^{(1)}, x_2^{(1)})), (x_1^{(2)}, x_2^{(2)}) \,, \quad Y = ((y_1^{(1)}, y_2^{(1)}), (y_1^{(2)}, y_2^{(2)})) \,. $$
(Also, yes, for the record, it would probably make sense to choose some way to structure these as a left or right [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). However the number of alleles can differ between loci.) So then
$$I = \frac{ \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i_1=1}^2 x_{i_1}^{(1)}y_{i_1}^{(1)} + \sum_{i_2=1}^2 x_{i_2}^{(2)}y_{i_2}^{(2)}  \right)
}{
\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i_1=1}^2 (x_{i_1}^{(1)})^2 + \sum_{i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_2}^{(2)})^2  \right)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{i_1=1}^2 (y_{i_1}^{(1)})^2 + \sum_{i_2=1}^2 (y_{i_2}^{(2)})^2  \right)}} \,. $$
So basically my proposed counterexample then, as mentioned above, suggests playing off the two kinds of symmetry against each other. Specifically, consider the special case when
$$(x_1^{(1)}, x_2^{(1)}) = (y_1^{(2)}, y_2^{(2)}) \quad \text{and} \quad (x_1^{(2)}, x_2^{(2)}) = (y_1^{(1)}, y_2^{(1)}) \,.$$
Substituting all $y$ terms in the above formula with $x$ terms, we get
$$\begin{array}{rcl}I & = & \frac{ \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 x_{i_1}^{(1)}x_{i_2}^{(2)} + \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 x_{i_2}^{(2)}x_{i_1}^{(1)}  \right)
}{
\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_1}^{(1)})^2 + \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_2}^{(2)})^2  \right)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_2}^{(2)})^2 + \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_1}^{(1)})^2  \right)}} \\
& = &  
\frac{ \displaystyle \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 x_{i_1}^{(1)}x_{i_2}^{(2)} 
}{
\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_1}^{(1)})^2 + \sum_{i_1=i_2=1}^2 (x_{i_2}^{(2)})^2  \right)}
\,. \end{array}\tag{special}$$
Unfortunately this can never be a counterexample, because we are asking for two vector $\vec{x}^{(1)}=:v$ and $\vec{x}^{(2)}=:w$ such that $2 v \bullet w = ||v||^2 + ||w||^2$, which is true if and only if $(v_1^2 - 2v_1w_1 + w_1^2) + (v_2^2 - 2v_2 w_2 + w_2^2) = (v_1 - w_1)^2 + (v_2 - w_2)^2 = 0$. And that's only possible when $v_1 = w_1$ and $v_2 = w_2$, i.e. when $v = w$.

In any case, if there is any counterexample, it should probably be possible to find with $L=2=I_1 = I_2$. But I haven't been able to show that.